# Django template - use 2 models to filter results

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Apologies if my question is not that clear. I'm new to Django and it's my first time to ask questions here as I can't seem to find solutions to my problem.

I've done research on how to use multiple models in Django template and succeeded to do so, however, one of my requirement is that each trucker in the list should show corresponding number of registered truck units but I can't seem to do this.

The output should be like this:

```
Truckers List
Registered Trucker  Number of units
Trucker #1          10
Trucker #2          5
...
Trucker #n          3
```

Should you have suggestions I highly appreciate it. Im using Django version 2.0.1 and Python 3.6 on Windows if that's relevant.

Here is my code:

***models.py***

```
class Trucker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TruckUnit(models.Model):
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    trucker = models.ForeignKey(Trucker, related_name='truckunits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.plate_number
```

***views.py***

```
class TruckerList(generic.ListView):
    model = Trucker
    context_object_name = 'trucker_list'
    queryset = Trucker.objects.all().order_by('name')
    template_name = 'trip_monitor/trucker_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self. **kwargs):
        context = super(TruckerList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['units'] = TruckUnit.objects.all()
        context['truckers'] = self.queryset
        return context
```

***urls.py***

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('truckers/', views.TruckerList.as_view(), name='trucker_list'),
]
```

***trucker_list.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h3>Trucker List</h3>
    {% if trucker_list %}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Registered Truckers</th>
                <th>Number of units</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for trucker in trucker_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ trucker.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ units.count }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {% else %}
    <p>No registered truckers yet</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
from django.db.models import Count
```

Then

```
queryset = Trucker.objects.all().annotate(Count("truckunits")).order_by('name')
```

Then in template

```
{% for trucker in trucker_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ trucker.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ trucker.truckunits__count }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the query inside your get_context_data, create a new context value like:

> > context['products'] = Products.objects.all()

and you will have the queryset at your template.

I hope it help you

Comment: in my views.py I already have the context['units'] = TruckUnit.objects.all() which is the one want need to count per Trucker in the template (trucker_list.html) however, I do not know how to achieve this.